# How to append text in a csv file at the end of each line Java?

Tags: java, csv, selenium

I have a csv file with testdata:

```
31-September-2017 01:52:57 02:11:25
31-September-2017 01:52:57 02:11:25
```

I want to write the test result(PASS/FAIL) for every line of data at the end of each line, like this:

```
31-September-2017 01:52:57 02:11:25 PASSED
31-September-2017 01:52:57 02:11:25 FAILED
```

I am using openCSV api to read the file content. When I open the same file using CSVWriter, it is deleting all the contents of the file. Used BufferedWriter as well, same problem.

Please suggest me how I can achieve this with the original contents of file remaining same, and appending the test result at the end of each line. Thanks.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the "edit" link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `BufferedReader` and `BufferedWriter` for this:

- Read the file line by line
- Write another file line by line
- Add the `PASSED` / `FAILED` to each line before writing
- Delete the old file and rename the new file

---

I'll try to explain why this will be the best way:

- Its efficient (`O(n)` while `n` is the size of the file)
- Easy to implement (Just about 20-30 lines of code for the reading and writing part)
- Will be readable and understandable (Readability is a very important point.)

Comment: Why can't we write in the same file, when I do that, Why does it delete the entire file contents

Comment: There are possibilities to write in the same file but they will overwrite the existing content after the filepointer. Example: The file looks like this `foo|||bar`. Now you write `"xyz"` after `|||`. The filecontent will look like this: `foo|||xyz`

Comment: Could you please explain me why it happens, so. as i am new to this.

Comment: An existing file basically looks like an array. There are bytes on indexes in the memory. Writing mid file does not shift all bytes after that to the right, but overwrites the bytes on the indexes after the filepointer. Please see the edit of my answer to see why reading/writing on 2 files is good/better

Comment: Thanks for your answer, It's clear to me now that it's the way FileWriter is been implemented. But just wondering why didn't they write an api, to be able to insert bytes in between file. Like give offset, insert there, then take offset+1 to length of the file data , and shift it to the right. Is there any specific reason?

Comment: Well the reason is quite simple: The way it's implemented is more efficient. (Over-)Writing a single character can be done in constant time (`O(1)`) while shifting all other bytes requires linear time (`O(n)`). When you're working on big files that will be relevant.

Comment: Thank you so much @ParkerHalo for patiently answering my queries.

Answer (score 0):

Something simillar like below should work with opencsv.

```
import com.opencsv.CSVReader;
import com.opencsv.CSVWriter;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class Example {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String fileName = "C:\\Users\\eritrean\\Desktop\\yourfile.csv";
            List<String[]> myEntries =  readFile(fileName);
            List<String[]> testedEntries = new ArrayList<>();
            for(String[] row : myEntries){
                String[] withTestResult = addTestResult(row,randomResult());
                testedEntries.add(withTestResult);
            }
            writeToFile(fileName,testedEntries);
        } catch (IOException ex) {

        }
    }
    public static List<String[]> readFile(String fileName) throws IOException {
        CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(fileName),'\t','\"',0);
        List<String[]> myEntries = reader.readAll();
        return myEntries;
    }

    public static String[] addTestResult(String[] row, String result){        
        return (String.join("\t", row)+"\t"+result).split("\t");
    }
    public static String randomResult(){  
        Random rand = new Random();
        return rand.nextBoolean()?"PASSED":"FAILED";
    }
    public static void writeToFile(String fileName, List<String[]> myEntries) throws IOException {
        try (CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(fileName), '\t',CSVWriter.NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER)) {
            for(String[] row: myEntries){
                writer.writeNext(row);
            }
        }
    }    
}
```